High CPU usage detected Message
I keep getting this popup that says
High CPU Usage Detected

It appears in a white box with rounded corners in the upper right of the screen whenever I watch a YouTube video in full screen (Edge, Windows 11). There is a blue circle timer animation.
After a few seconds it goes away. Some random time later it happens again.
The video playback is still fine with no dropped frames or audio glitches. So I don't really care if my CPU usage is high. I just want to disable the message.
I have tried googling things like High CPU usage Detected message/popup chrome, edge, windows 11, how to disable etc.
The only results talk about how chrome is CPU greedy and how they can see this in task manager. Nothing about a popup message.
I remember there used to be a settings page in Chrome/Edge that was just a list of variable names with settings you could change. Internal secret features of Chrome. You could use it to enable and disable certain features of the browser. I have tried googling this but I guess it doesn't exist anymore?
I have searched for CPU in the main settings page in Edge and there is no setting to control this message.
I would simply like to disable the message. But I am unsure how to determine if this is an Edge or Windows 11 issue so I don't know who to ask for help or who to report the ?bug? to. Assuming Edge is the issue.

is the message inside your browser/youtube? it looks like a youtube feature: https://usercomp.com/news/1232087/solving-high-cpu-usage-pop-ups-during-youtube

@frankthomas usercomp(dot)com has never loaded for me. It seems to exist only to feed answers to LLMs and get highly ranked by them, but does not accept actual browsing traffic.

@music2myear, not sure what to tell you. what I saw at that link was an article describing this feature of youtube, and describing some of the things you can try to do with their settings to try to minimize it, like tweaking hardware acceleration features. can't say I've heard of this site before, but the article seemed pertinent. what I most wanted was for the op to confirm that it is the youtube feature described, so that troubleshooting could begin from there.

Were you able to get to the site? The answers presented in the search synopsis always seem good from this site too. I'm just unable to reach the site from personal or work devices and connections, for whatever reason.

Yeah, I was able to load and read the page. would be embarrassing to post a bad link, so sorry to hear you are having trouble with it.

If I clicked on the popup message a few times it opened a sidebar in Edge called Browser essentials where I was able to report that they were sending too many notifications.

How is this an answer to your question? You have not specified how to disable the message itself.
